# What is the exact definition of heat capacity? Was it derived experimentally?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

The usual definition of [heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) $C$ is that when we put a certain amount of heat $dQ $, the temperature will rise by $CdT$. But why is it a constant?

In better terms why is heat strictly proportional to the temperature, with nothing else intervening in the formula .

Was it an experimental discovery or is there some theory behind it?

Comment: It is not only variable, but also a process-dependent: ther are $C_V$ and $C_P$. Of course, it is experimentally known since ages. And there is nothing unusual in the relationship $dQ=C(T)dT$.

Comment: In thermodynamics, we no longer use the definition dQ=CdT because it does not generally apply.  We use $$C_v=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V$$and$$C_p=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P$$

Comment: @ChetMiller that's an answer

Comment: Sarah, heat is proportional to $\Delta T$, not $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a constant but it is often approximated to be constant.It depends on the temperature, pressure, volume,etc of the system.

Consider for example a solid crystal.Below a certain temperature, the Debye temperature, the heat capacity of a crystal increases with increase in Temperature but after Debye temperature,it becomes a constant.

In beginner courses,it is treated as a constant in ideal cases for simplicity.

---

I think,first the theory must have been formulated which must have been then verified and improved with experiments(same as for most Physics definitions)